# Create a function that takes a string and returns either true or false depending on whether or not the string has repeated characters

Tags: javascript

```js
var arr = [];
repeatcount = 0;

function isogram(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    for (var g = 0; g < arr.length; g++) {
      if (str[i] != arr[g]) {
        arr.push(str[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  if (arr.length != str.length) {
    return false
  } else {
    return true
  }
}


document.write(isogram("jiang"));

console.log(arr);
```

When I am using console.log(arr), I found that the arr is empty, and I don't know why. The approach I am using is basically creating an array that stores non-repeating character then compare the length, if the length is different then there is repeating character.

Comment: `arr.length` is initially `0`. So your inner loop will never run

Comment: That's the problem I thought of,  is there any way for me to fix it?

Comment: @JiangYuxin use `str.length` instead of `arr.length`. There are however efficient solutions to the actual problem you are looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656708/check-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string-javascript/33657083

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `arr` length at the beginning equals to `0`, the inner loop is never fired.

```
g < arr.length // is always false
```

What I would suggest you is to get rid of the inner loop and use a simple condition instead - if current letter is not inside `arr` yet - push it, if there is - don't.

```js
var arr = [];
repeatcount = 0;

function isogram(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (arr.indexOf(str[i]) === -1) {
       arr.push(str[i]);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  return arr.length === str.length;
}

console.log(isogram("jiang"));
console.log(isogram("jiiang"));
```

**Bonus**: One line solution:

```js
const isogram = (str) => [...str].length === [...new Set(str)].length;

console.log(isogram("jiang"));
console.log(isogram("jiiang"));
```

Comment: arr.indexOf(str[i]) === -1 . what does the -1 mean? Sorry if the question is stupid, I just started learning js

Comment: The function could also return *false* as soon as the *if* condition is false, or *true* otherwise. ;-)

Comment: @JiangYuxin If there is no specified element inside array yet, it's index is equal to `-1`