# Function not returning anything at all but console.log returns something

Tags: javascript

I am trying to run this function in js , this function should check if string has any repeated letters and return false if any and true if not but it does not return anything . I am trying to compare two strings and return true or false based on that .

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
  let str1 = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  //console.log(str.toLowerCase())
  let str2 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    //console.log(str1[i])
    if (str2.indexOf(str1[i]) === -1) {
      str2.push(str1[i])
    }
  }
  //console.log(str2)
  if (str2 === str1) {
    return true;
  } else return false;
}


console.log(isIsogram("abba"))
```

Comment: You can't compare arrays like that.

Comment: str2 is initilized as an Array and str1 a String. You cant compare an array and a string. change str2 to String.

Comment: I made you a snippet.

Comment: When you return a value from a function you have to consume it somehow.  For example, `var result = isIsogram("abba");`

Comment: Thank you so much,guys! I am new to coding ,I stared with Html , css , working on js. Let me try that .

Answer (score 1):

You could try and use the following:

```
 function hasRepeatedChar(text){ 
     return text.split("").some(
            function(v,i,a){
                return a.lastIndexOf(v)!=i
            }
     );
 }
```

This answer explains it very well:
[Check for repeated characters in a string Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656708/check-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could optimize your algorithm like this:

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
  let foundChars = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      const char = str[i];
      if (foundChars.includes(char)) {
          return false;
      }
      foundChars.push(char);
  }
  
  return true;
}


console.log(isIsogram("ab"));
console.log(isIsogram("abba"));
```

Answer (score 0):

One does not simply compare two arrays. But you can join them into string first, then compare.

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
  let str1 = str.toLowerCase().split("");
  
  let str2 = []
  for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    
    if (str2.indexOf(str1[i]) === -1) {
      str2.push(str1[i])
    }
  }

  if (str2.join('') === str1.join('')) {
    return true;
  } else return false;
}


console.log(isIsogram("abba"))
```

Besides, I have a simpler solution for you, leveraging `Set`.

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
  return new Set(str.split('')).size === str.length
}

console.log(isIsogram("abba"), isIsogram("abc"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare two arrays with characters in them using `str2 === str1`. Unfortunately strict equality operator, `===`, is meant to compare primitive types like strings, or numbers NOT arrays.

In your code, quickest solution would be to convert both `str1` and `str2` to strings using join method and then compare them like `str2.join('') === str1.join('')`.

Read more about equality check in javascript [here](https://javascript.info/comparison) and about join method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

P.S. - This is not the best/optimal approach, but simple enough to begin to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```js
function isIsogram(str) {
    let str1 = str.toLowerCase().split("");
    let str2 = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        if (str2.indexOf(str1[i]) === -1) {
            str2.push(str1[i]);
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}


console.log(isIsogram("abba"));
```

Comment: Could you explain why the function was not returning anything in the first place?