# search for repeating characters and remove them from array js

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, web-scraping

I have multiple random arrays in which i put into arrays from scraping a website.

I was wondering if I could search an array and remove the repeating html that is in the array

```js
arr = [{
    "post_title": "When Climate and Energy Collide – Planning for a Carbon Neutral Future as the Climate Changes",
    "post_link": "/event/21s3wor",
    "post_img": "https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/event-img-thumb/Electric%20grid.png?itok=YVAj84AW",
    "post_date": "September 14, 2021",
    "event_type": "Public Lecture",
    "post_content": [
      "<div class=\"field field-name-public-lecture-watch- field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><section class=\"block block-views block-views-items-list-by-event-block-4\">\n  \n        \n    \n    <div class=\"view view-items-list-by-event view-id-items_list_by_event view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-7bf8b6c0bb0903b64fc25e83b84152e8\">\n        \n  \n  \n      <div class=\"view-content\">\n        <div class=\"views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last\">\n      \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-date-1\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <h3></h3>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-subtitle\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><h6>Presented by: <a href=\"/redhen/contact/3317\">Amber Mahone</a> </h6></div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"flex-video vimeo\">        <div><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXRI_QkFe5Q\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <p></p><p>Recent extreme weather events have exposed the vulnerability of our electric grid to a changing climate, while underscoring the urgent need to reduce greenhouse gas emissions from the energy sector. Deep decarbonization scenarios paint a vivid picture of what is needed to transition the U.S. economy to a clean energy, carbon-neutral future. Energy efficiency, electrification of transportation and buildings, low-carbon fuels, clean electricity, plus carbon dioxide removal and sequestration, are all needed at massive scale to reduce greenhouse gas emissions over the next 30 years. </p>\n<p>How can we plan for, and execute on, this energy transition as climate change continues to accelerate over this same period? Where are our blind spots in planning for this clean energy transition, and how could climate science better inform these efforts? This lecture by Amber Mahone, a partner at Energy and Environmental Economics, Inc. (E3), is followed by an interactive Q&amp;A session.</p>\n<p></p>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><a href=\"#\" data-reveal-id=\"ModalWOR-23608\" class=\"radius button small secondary\">View Video with Presentation Materials</a></div>\n\n<div id=\"ModalWOR-23608\" class=\"reveal-modal large\" data-reveal=\"\" aria-labelledby=\"worModalTitle\" aria-hidden=\"true\" role=\"dialog\">\n<h3></h3><h5><strong> When Climate and Energy Collide – Planning for a Carbon Neutral Future as the Climate Changes</strong><subheader>  </subheader></h5>\n<div class=\"ds-1col node node-library-item view-mode-modal_view_mode view-mode-modal_view_mode clearfix \">\n\n  \n  <div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><div class=\"even flex-video\"><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXRI_QkFe5Q\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div><div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><h2><span>Presentation Materials</span></h2><div class=\"field field-name-field-lib-doc-main field-type-file field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><object id=\"pdf_reader\" data=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><embed src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. <a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html\">Download adobe Acrobat </a> or <a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf\">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p></object><a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf\" class=\"pdf-reader-download-link\">Click here to download the PDF file.</a></div></div><div class=\"collapsible large-12 columns  speed-fast effect-none\">\n      <h3><span class=\"field-group-format-toggler\">Details</span></h3>\n      </div></div></div> \n  <a class=\"close-reveal-modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">×</a>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-edit-node\">        <span class=\"field-content\"></span>  </div>  </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n</div>  \n  </section></div>"
    ],
    "description": [
      "<legend><span class=\"fieldset-legend\">Description</span></legend><div class=\"fieldset-wrapper\"><div class=\"field field-name-session-description-header field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\">\n</div><p>Recent extreme weather events have exposed the vulnerability of our electric grid to a changing climate, while underscoring the urgent need to reduce greenhouse gas emissions from the energy sector. Deep decarbonization scenarios paint a vivid picture of what is needed to transition the U.S. economy to a clean energy, carbon-neutral future. Energy efficiency, electrification of transportation and buildings, low-carbon fuels, clean electricity, plus carbon dioxide removal and sequestration, are all needed at massive scale to reduce greenhouse gas emissions over the next 30 years. How can we plan for, and execute on, this energy transition as climate change continues to accelerate over this same period? Where are our blind spots in planning for this clean energy transition, and how could climate science better inform these efforts?</p>\n</div>"
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Halting Climate Change: Why Zero Emissions Is Only the Beginning",
    "post_link": "/event/21s2wor",
    "post_img": "https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/event-img-thumb/Smokestacks.png?itok=sAb6VaSc",
    "post_date": "July 20, 2021",
    "event_type": "Public Lecture",
    "post_content": [
      "<div class=\"field field-name-public-lecture-watch- field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><section class=\"block block-views block-views-items-list-by-event-block-4\">\n  \n        \n    \n    <div class=\"view view-items-list-by-event view-id-items_list_by_event view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-3e13c1cd70a3a49df608e42deca7844e\">\n        \n  \n  \n      <div class=\"view-content\">\n        <div class=\"views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last\">\n      \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-date-1\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <h3></h3>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-subtitle\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><h6>Presented by: <a href=\"/redhen/contact/1410\">Joeri Rogelj</a> </h6></div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"flex-video vimeo\">        <div><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/7mYSiGBPYmM\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <p></p>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><a href=\"#\" data-reveal-id=\"ModalWOR-23573\" class=\"radius button small secondary\">View Video with Presentation Materials</a></div>\n\n<div id=\"ModalWOR-23573\" class=\"reveal-modal large\" data-reveal=\"\" aria-labelledby=\"worModalTitle\" aria-hidden=\"true\" role=\"dialog\">\n<h3></h3><h5><strong>Halting Climate Change: Why Zero Emissions Is Only the Beginning</strong><subheader>  </subheader></h5>\n<div class=\"ds-1col node node-library-item view-mode-modal_view_mode view-mode-modal_view_mode clearfix \">\n\n  \n  <div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><div class=\"even flex-video\"><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/7mYSiGBPYmM\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div><div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><h2><span>Presentation Materials</span></h2><div class=\"field field-name-field-lib-doc-main field-type-file field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><object id=\"pdf_reader\" data=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><embed src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. <a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html\">Download adobe Acrobat </a> or <a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf\">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p></object><a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf\" class=\"pdf-reader-download-link\">Click here to download the PDF file.</a></div></div><div class=\"collapsible large-12 columns  speed-fast effect-none\">\n      <h3><span class=\"field-group-format-toggler\">Details</span></h3>\n      </div></div></div> \n  <a class=\"close-reveal-modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">×</a>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-edit-node\">        <span class=\"field-content\"></span>  </div>  </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n</div>  \n  </section></div>"
    ],
    "description": [
      "<legend><span class=\"fieldset-legend\">Description</span></legend><div class=\"fieldset-wrapper\"><div class=\"field field-name-session-description-header field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\">\n</div><p>The 2015 U.N. Paris Agreement has set a goal of keeping global warming well below 2°C, and preferably to 1.5°C. In this lecture, we will look at what that means for the amount of carbon dioxide that can still be emitted, the emissions pathways we need to follow, and why reaching net-zero emissions is only the beginning of a much longer journey.&nbsp;</p>\n<div class=\"label-above\">Workshop Topic (s):&nbsp;</div><ul><li class=\"even\">Climate Variability and Change (including Climate Modeling)</li></ul></div>"
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Drought, Fire, and Flood: Monitoring and Modeling More Frequent Catastrophes",
    "post_link": "/event/19s2wor",
    "post_img": "https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/event-img-thumb/duffy-brook-364577-unsplash_0.jpg?itok=xDmuPJMR",
    "post_date": "May 22, 2019",
    "event_type": "Public Lecture",
    "post_content": [
      "<div class=\"field field-name-public-lecture-watch- field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><section class=\"block block-views block-views-items-list-by-event-block-4\">\n  \n        \n    \n    <div class=\"view view-items-list-by-event view-id-items_list_by_event view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-6f996c6ab232c0415892dc1c8194aa3e\">\n        \n  \n  \n      <div class=\"view-content\">\n        <div class=\"views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last\">\n      \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-date-1\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <h3></h3>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-subtitle\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><h6>Presented by: <a href=\"/redhen/contact/3076\">Christopher Funk</a> </h6></div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"flex-video vimeo\">        <div><iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/400722437?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe><p>Funk-WOR-19-05-22-Vimeo from <a href=\"https://vimeo.com/aspenglobal\">AGCI</a> on <a href=\"https://vimeo.com\">Vimeo</a>.</p>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <p></p><p>Dr. Chris Funk of the USGS and UC Santa Barbara explores the relationship between climate change, catastrophic events, and human response. Between 2015 and 2018 an unprecedented series of droughts, floods, fires, heat waves and hurricanes took the lives and livelihoods of thousands of people, resulting in over $700 billion dollars in damages, costs similar in magnitude to a large scale war. The frequency and costs of weather and climate related catastrophes are increasing dramatically, as a growing population and a warmer climate place more people in harm's way. Warming of the atmosphere can both increase the intensity of extreme precipitation and cyclones, while also increasing the impact of droughts and the extent of wildfires. Warming of the oceans can lead to coral bleaching and more intense wet or dry cycles. Against this back- drop of need, however, improved monitoring systems and models can help us improve our understanding of our physical, social and economic systems and help us manage risk and work towards a more sustainable future.</p>\n<p></p>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><a href=\"#\" data-reveal-id=\"ModalWOR-23362\" class=\"radius button small secondary\">View Video with Presentation Materials</a></div>\n\n<div id=\"ModalWOR-23362\" class=\"reveal-modal large\" data-reveal=\"\" aria-labelledby=\"worModalTitle\" aria-hidden=\"true\" role=\"dialog\">\n<h3></h3><h5><strong>Drought, Fire, and Flood: Monitoring and Modeling More Frequent Catastrophes</strong><subheader>  </subheader></h5>\n<div class=\"ds-1col node node-library-item view-mode-modal_view_mode view-mode-modal_view_mode clearfix \">\n\n  \n  <div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><div class=\"even flex-video\"><iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/400722437?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe><p>Funk-WOR-19-05-22-Vimeo from <a href=\"https://vimeo.com/aspenglobal\">AGCI</a> on <a href=\"https://vimeo.com\">Vimeo</a>.</p>\n</div><div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><h2><span>Presentation Materials</span></h2><div class=\"field field-name-field-lib-doc-main field-type-file field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><object id=\"pdf_reader\" data=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><embed src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. <a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html\">Download adobe Acrobat </a> or <a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf\">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p></object><a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf\" class=\"pdf-reader-download-link\">Click here to download the PDF file.</a></div></div><div class=\"collapsible large-12 columns  speed-fast effect-none\">\n      <h3><span class=\"field-group-format-toggler\">Details</span></h3>\n      </div></div></div> \n  <a class=\"close-reveal-modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">×</a>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-edit-node\">        <span class=\"field-content\"></span>  </div>  </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n</div>  \n  </section></div><p class=\"even\"></p><p>Dr. Chris Funk of the USGS and UC Santa Barbara explores the relationship between climate change, catastrophic events, and human response. Between 2015 and 2018 an unprecedented series of droughts, floods, fires, heat waves and hurricanes took the lives and livelihoods of thousands of people, resulting in over $700 billion dollars in damages, costs similar in magnitude to a large scale war. The frequency and costs of weather and climate related catastrophes are increasing dramatically, as a growing population and a warmer climate place more people in harm's way. Warming of the atmosphere can both increase the intensity of extreme precipitation and cyclones, while also increasing the impact of droughts and the extent of wildfires. Warming of the oceans can lead to coral bleaching and more intense wet or dry cycles. Against this back- drop of need, however, improved monitoring systems and models can help us improve our understanding of our physical, social and economic systems and help us manage risk and work towards a more sustainable future.</p>\n<p></p>"
    ],
    "description": [
      "<legend><span class=\"fieldset-legend\">Description</span></legend><div class=\"fieldset-wrapper\"><div class=\"field field-name-session-description-header field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\">\n</div><div class=\"even right\"><blockimg typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/event-photos/ChrisPhoto%20%281%29.jpg?itok=_pa7GCvv\" width=\"480\" height=\"473\" alt=\"\"></blockimg></div><p>Dr. Chris Funk of the USGS and UC Santa Barbara explores the relationship between climate change, catastrophic events, and human response. Between 2015 and 2018 an unprecedented series of droughts, floods, fires, heat waves and hurricanes took the lives and livelihoods of thousands of people, resulting in over $700 billion dollars in damages, costs similar in magnitude to a large scale war. The frequency and costs of weather and climate related catastrophes are increasing dramatically, as a growing population and a warmer climate place more people in harm's way. Warming of the atmosphere can both increase the intensity of extreme precipitation and cyclones, while also increasing the impact of droughts and the extent of wildfires. Warming of the oceans can lead to coral bleaching and more intense wet or dry cycles. Against this back- drop of need, however, improved monitoring systems and models can help us improve our understanding of our physical, social and economic systems and help us manage risk and work towards a more sustainable future. </p>\n<p>About Dr. Funk:<br>\nDr. Chris Funk is a Senior Research Geographer for the USGS EROS Early Warning and Environmental Monitoring Group and is a Research Professor at the University of California Santa Barbara (UCSB). Much of his work centers on the study of extreme events and early warning systems. His research interests include using climate predictions to improve food security, with emphasis on developing nations in Africa. He has published numerous papers on drought monitoring, climate impacts, and weather extremes and has facilitated coordinating efforts across national and international institutions, including establishing the Climate Hazards Group in 2003 to facilitate collaboration between the USGS and UCSB. Dr. Funk’s public lecture will focus on how models and monitoring can be used to prepare for catastrophic events and mitigate their devastating impacts.</p>\n<div class=\"label-above\">Workshop Topic (s):&nbsp;</div><ul><li class=\"even\">Atmospheric Composition</li><li class=\"odd\">Carbon Cycle</li><li class=\"even\">Climate Variability and Change (including Climate Modeling)</li><li class=\"odd\">Human Contributions &amp; Responses</li><li class=\"even\">Land-Use/Land-Cover Change</li><li class=\"odd\">Water Cycle</li></ul></div>"
    ]
  }
]
```

this is not all of the objects but only 3 of 94 in the whole array. In the post content, there is a repeating url

in the first object, this is repeated twice

```
<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXRI_QkFe5Q\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>
```

and in the second object

```
<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/7mYSiGBPYmM\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>
```

third object

```
<iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/400722437?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>
```

is it even possible to search just the post_content array and find the repeating url and or html and remove the second/first instance of it?

Comment: [check for repeated characters in a string javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33656708/463206)  It is worth the time to go through the entire posting

Comment: So are you specifically trying to scrape for video links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go with fragments and remove

```js
arr.forEach(({post_content},i)=>{
  const fragment = document.createElement("div");
  fragment.innerHTML = post_content.join('<hr/>');
  const ifrs = fragment.querySelectorAll('iframe')
  const srcs = []
  ifrs.forEach(ifr => {
    if (srcs.includes(ifr.src)) ifr.remove()
    else srcs.push(ifr.src)
  })
  console.log(srcs)
  arr[i].post_content = fragment.innerHTML
})
console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script>arr = [{
    "post_title": "When Climate and Energy Collide – Planning for a Carbon Neutral Future as the Climate Changes",
    "post_link": "/event/21s3wor",
    "post_img": "https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/event-img-thumb/Electric%20grid.png?itok=YVAj84AW",
    "post_date": "September 14, 2021",
    "event_type": "Public Lecture",
    "post_content": [
      "<div class=\"field field-name-public-lecture-watch- field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><section class=\"block block-views block-views-items-list-by-event-block-4\">\n  \n        \n    \n    <div class=\"view view-items-list-by-event view-id-items_list_by_event view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-7bf8b6c0bb0903b64fc25e83b84152e8\">\n        \n  \n  \n      <div class=\"view-content\">\n        <div class=\"views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last\">\n      \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-date-1\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <h3></h3>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-subtitle\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><h6>Presented by: <a href=\"/redhen/contact/3317\">Amber Mahone</a> </h6></div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"flex-video vimeo\">        <div><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXRI_QkFe5Q\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <p></p><p>Recent extreme weather events have exposed the vulnerability of our electric grid to a changing climate, while underscoring the urgent need to reduce greenhouse gas emissions from the energy sector. Deep decarbonization scenarios paint a vivid picture of what is needed to transition the U.S. economy to a clean energy, carbon-neutral future. Energy efficiency, electrification of transportation and buildings, low-carbon fuels, clean electricity, plus carbon dioxide removal and sequestration, are all needed at massive scale to reduce greenhouse gas emissions over the next 30 years. </p>\n<p>How can we plan for, and execute on, this energy transition as climate change continues to accelerate over this same period? Where are our blind spots in planning for this clean energy transition, and how could climate science better inform these efforts? This lecture by Amber Mahone, a partner at Energy and Environmental Economics, Inc. (E3), is followed by an interactive Q&amp;A session.</p>\n<p></p>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><a href=\"#\" data-reveal-id=\"ModalWOR-23608\" class=\"radius button small secondary\">View Video with Presentation Materials</a></div>\n\n<div id=\"ModalWOR-23608\" class=\"reveal-modal large\" data-reveal=\"\" aria-labelledby=\"worModalTitle\" aria-hidden=\"true\" role=\"dialog\">\n<h3></h3><h5><strong> When Climate and Energy Collide – Planning for a Carbon Neutral Future as the Climate Changes</strong><subheader>  </subheader></h5>\n<div class=\"ds-1col node node-library-item view-mode-modal_view_mode view-mode-modal_view_mode clearfix \">\n\n  \n  <div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><div class=\"even flex-video\"><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/pXRI_QkFe5Q\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div><div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><h2><span>Presentation Materials</span></h2><div class=\"field field-name-field-lib-doc-main field-type-file field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><object id=\"pdf_reader\" data=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><embed src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. <a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html\">Download adobe Acrobat </a> or <a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf\">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p></object><a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/When%20Climate%20and%20Energy%20Collide_Mahone_Sep2021.pdf\" class=\"pdf-reader-download-link\">Click here to download the PDF file.</a></div></div><div class=\"collapsible large-12 columns  speed-fast effect-none\">\n      <h3><span class=\"field-group-format-toggler\">Details</span></h3>\n      </div></div></div> \n  <a class=\"close-reveal-modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">×</a>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-edit-node\">        <span class=\"field-content\"></span>  </div>  </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n</div>  \n  </section></div>"
    ],
    "description": [
      "<legend><span class=\"fieldset-legend\">Description</span></legend><div class=\"fieldset-wrapper\"><div class=\"field field-name-session-description-header field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\">\n</div><p>Recent extreme weather events have exposed the vulnerability of our electric grid to a changing climate, while underscoring the urgent need to reduce greenhouse gas emissions from the energy sector. Deep decarbonization scenarios paint a vivid picture of what is needed to transition the U.S. economy to a clean energy, carbon-neutral future. Energy efficiency, electrification of transportation and buildings, low-carbon fuels, clean electricity, plus carbon dioxide removal and sequestration, are all needed at massive scale to reduce greenhouse gas emissions over the next 30 years. How can we plan for, and execute on, this energy transition as climate change continues to accelerate over this same period? Where are our blind spots in planning for this clean energy transition, and how could climate science better inform these efforts?</p>\n</div>"
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Halting Climate Change: Why Zero Emissions Is Only the Beginning",
    "post_link": "/event/21s2wor",
    "post_img": "https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/event-img-thumb/Smokestacks.png?itok=sAb6VaSc",
    "post_date": "July 20, 2021",
    "event_type": "Public Lecture",
    "post_content": [
      "<div class=\"field field-name-public-lecture-watch- field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><section class=\"block block-views block-views-items-list-by-event-block-4\">\n  \n        \n    \n    <div class=\"view view-items-list-by-event view-id-items_list_by_event view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-3e13c1cd70a3a49df608e42deca7844e\">\n        \n  \n  \n      <div class=\"view-content\">\n        <div class=\"views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last\">\n      \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-date-1\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <h3></h3>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-subtitle\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><h6>Presented by: <a href=\"/redhen/contact/1410\">Joeri Rogelj</a> </h6></div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"flex-video vimeo\">        <div><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/7mYSiGBPYmM\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <p></p>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><a href=\"#\" data-reveal-id=\"ModalWOR-23573\" class=\"radius button small secondary\">View Video with Presentation Materials</a></div>\n\n<div id=\"ModalWOR-23573\" class=\"reveal-modal large\" data-reveal=\"\" aria-labelledby=\"worModalTitle\" aria-hidden=\"true\" role=\"dialog\">\n<h3></h3><h5><strong>Halting Climate Change: Why Zero Emissions Is Only the Beginning</strong><subheader>  </subheader></h5>\n<div class=\"ds-1col node node-library-item view-mode-modal_view_mode view-mode-modal_view_mode clearfix \">\n\n  \n  <div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><div class=\"even flex-video\"><iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/7mYSiGBPYmM\" title=\"YouTube video player\" allow=\"accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"560\" height=\"315\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe></div><div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><h2><span>Presentation Materials</span></h2><div class=\"field field-name-field-lib-doc-main field-type-file field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><object id=\"pdf_reader\" data=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><embed src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. <a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html\">Download adobe Acrobat </a> or <a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf\">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p></object><a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/Presentation_JoeriROGELJ_WalterOrrRoberts_PublicLecture_Distri.pdf\" class=\"pdf-reader-download-link\">Click here to download the PDF file.</a></div></div><div class=\"collapsible large-12 columns  speed-fast effect-none\">\n      <h3><span class=\"field-group-format-toggler\">Details</span></h3>\n      </div></div></div> \n  <a class=\"close-reveal-modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">×</a>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-edit-node\">        <span class=\"field-content\"></span>  </div>  </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n</div>  \n  </section></div>"
    ],
    "description": [
      "<legend><span class=\"fieldset-legend\">Description</span></legend><div class=\"fieldset-wrapper\"><div class=\"field field-name-session-description-header field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\">\n</div><p>The 2015 U.N. Paris Agreement has set a goal of keeping global warming well below 2°C, and preferably to 1.5°C. In this lecture, we will look at what that means for the amount of carbon dioxide that can still be emitted, the emissions pathways we need to follow, and why reaching net-zero emissions is only the beginning of a much longer journey.&nbsp;</p>\n<div class=\"label-above\">Workshop Topic (s):&nbsp;</div><ul><li class=\"even\">Climate Variability and Change (including Climate Modeling)</li></ul></div>"
    ]
  },
  {
    "post_title": "Drought, Fire, and Flood: Monitoring and Modeling More Frequent Catastrophes",
    "post_link": "/event/19s2wor",
    "post_img": "https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/event-img-thumb/duffy-brook-364577-unsplash_0.jpg?itok=xDmuPJMR",
    "post_date": "May 22, 2019",
    "event_type": "Public Lecture",
    "post_content": [
      "<div class=\"field field-name-public-lecture-watch- field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><section class=\"block block-views block-views-items-list-by-event-block-4\">\n  \n        \n    \n    <div class=\"view view-items-list-by-event view-id-items_list_by_event view-display-id-block_4 view-dom-id-6f996c6ab232c0415892dc1c8194aa3e\">\n        \n  \n  \n      <div class=\"view-content\">\n        <div class=\"views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last\">\n      \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-date-1\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <h3></h3>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-field-lib-subtitle\">        <div class=\"field-content\"></div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><h6>Presented by: <a href=\"/redhen/contact/3076\">Christopher Funk</a> </h6></div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"flex-video vimeo\">        <div><iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/400722437?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe><p>Funk-WOR-19-05-22-Vimeo from <a href=\"https://vimeo.com/aspenglobal\">AGCI</a> on <a href=\"https://vimeo.com\">Vimeo</a>.</p>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div>        <p></p><p>Dr. Chris Funk of the USGS and UC Santa Barbara explores the relationship between climate change, catastrophic events, and human response. Between 2015 and 2018 an unprecedented series of droughts, floods, fires, heat waves and hurricanes took the lives and livelihoods of thousands of people, resulting in over $700 billion dollars in damages, costs similar in magnitude to a large scale war. The frequency and costs of weather and climate related catastrophes are increasing dramatically, as a growing population and a warmer climate place more people in harm's way. Warming of the atmosphere can both increase the intensity of extreme precipitation and cyclones, while also increasing the impact of droughts and the extent of wildfires. Warming of the oceans can lead to coral bleaching and more intense wet or dry cycles. Against this back- drop of need, however, improved monitoring systems and models can help us improve our understanding of our physical, social and economic systems and help us manage risk and work towards a more sustainable future.</p>\n<p></p>  </div>  \n  <div>        <div><a href=\"#\" data-reveal-id=\"ModalWOR-23362\" class=\"radius button small secondary\">View Video with Presentation Materials</a></div>\n\n<div id=\"ModalWOR-23362\" class=\"reveal-modal large\" data-reveal=\"\" aria-labelledby=\"worModalTitle\" aria-hidden=\"true\" role=\"dialog\">\n<h3></h3><h5><strong>Drought, Fire, and Flood: Monitoring and Modeling More Frequent Catastrophes</strong><subheader>  </subheader></h5>\n<div class=\"ds-1col node node-library-item view-mode-modal_view_mode view-mode-modal_view_mode clearfix \">\n\n  \n  <div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><div class=\"even flex-video\"><iframe src=\"https://player.vimeo.com/video/400722437?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0\" allow=\"autoplay; fullscreen\" allowfullscreen=\"\" width=\"640\" height=\"360\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe><p>Funk-WOR-19-05-22-Vimeo from <a href=\"https://vimeo.com/aspenglobal\">AGCI</a> on <a href=\"https://vimeo.com\">Vimeo</a>.</p>\n</div><div class=\"large-12 small-12 columns\"><h2><span>Presentation Materials</span></h2><div class=\"field field-name-field-lib-doc-main field-type-file field-label-hidden field-wrapper\"><object id=\"pdf_reader\" data=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><embed src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf#view=Fit\" type=\"application/pdf\" width=\"100%\" height=\"450px\"><p>It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. <a href=\"http://www.adobe.com/products/reader.html\">Download adobe Acrobat </a> or <a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf\">click here to download the PDF file.</a></p></object><a href=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/pdfs/lib/main/19s2_05_22_1800_WOR_Funk_AGCI_Drought_Fire_Flood_Funk_v2.pdf\" class=\"pdf-reader-download-link\">Click here to download the PDF file.</a></div></div><div class=\"collapsible large-12 columns  speed-fast effect-none\">\n      <h3><span class=\"field-group-format-toggler\">Details</span></h3>\n      </div></div></div> \n  <a class=\"close-reveal-modal\" aria-label=\"Close\">×</a>\n</div>  </div>  \n  <div class=\"views-field views-field-edit-node\">        <span class=\"field-content\"></span>  </div>  </div>\n    </div>\n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n</div>  \n  </section></div><p class=\"even\"></p><p>Dr. Chris Funk of the USGS and UC Santa Barbara explores the relationship between climate change, catastrophic events, and human response. Between 2015 and 2018 an unprecedented series of droughts, floods, fires, heat waves and hurricanes took the lives and livelihoods of thousands of people, resulting in over $700 billion dollars in damages, costs similar in magnitude to a large scale war. The frequency and costs of weather and climate related catastrophes are increasing dramatically, as a growing population and a warmer climate place more people in harm's way. Warming of the atmosphere can both increase the intensity of extreme precipitation and cyclones, while also increasing the impact of droughts and the extent of wildfires. Warming of the oceans can lead to coral bleaching and more intense wet or dry cycles. Against this back- drop of need, however, improved monitoring systems and models can help us improve our understanding of our physical, social and economic systems and help us manage risk and work towards a more sustainable future.</p>\n<p></p>"
    ],
    "description": [
      "<legend><span class=\"fieldset-legend\">Description</span></legend><div class=\"fieldset-wrapper\"><div class=\"field field-name-session-description-header field-type-ds field-label-hidden field-wrapper\">\n</div><div class=\"even right\"><blockimg typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"https://www.agci.org/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/event-photos/ChrisPhoto%20%281%29.jpg?itok=_pa7GCvv\" width=\"480\" height=\"473\" alt=\"\"></blockimg></div><p>Dr. Chris Funk of the USGS and UC Santa Barbara explores the relationship between climate change, catastrophic events, and human response. Between 2015 and 2018 an unprecedented series of droughts, floods, fires, heat waves and hurricanes took the lives and livelihoods of thousands of people, resulting in over $700 billion dollars in damages, costs similar in magnitude to a large scale war. The frequency and costs of weather and climate related catastrophes are increasing dramatically, as a growing population and a warmer climate place more people in harm's way. Warming of the atmosphere can both increase the intensity of extreme precipitation and cyclones, while also increasing the impact of droughts and the extent of wildfires. Warming of the oceans can lead to coral bleaching and more intense wet or dry cycles. Against this back- drop of need, however, improved monitoring systems and models can help us improve our understanding of our physical, social and economic systems and help us manage risk and work towards a more sustainable future. </p>\n<p>About Dr. Funk:<br>\nDr. Chris Funk is a Senior Research Geographer for the USGS EROS Early Warning and Environmental Monitoring Group and is a Research Professor at the University of California Santa Barbara (UCSB). Much of his work centers on the study of extreme events and early warning systems. His research interests include using climate predictions to improve food security, with emphasis on developing nations in Africa. He has published numerous papers on drought monitoring, climate impacts, and weather extremes and has facilitated coordinating efforts across national and international institutions, including establishing the Climate Hazards Group in 2003 to facilitate collaboration between the USGS and UCSB. Dr. Funk’s public lecture will focus on how models and monitoring can be used to prepare for catastrophic events and mitigate their devastating impacts.</p>\n<div class=\"label-above\">Workshop Topic (s):&nbsp;</div><ul><li class=\"even\">Atmospheric Composition</li><li class=\"odd\">Carbon Cycle</li><li class=\"even\">Climate Variability and Change (including Climate Modeling)</li><li class=\"odd\">Human Contributions &amp; Responses</li><li class=\"even\">Land-Use/Land-Cover Change</li><li class=\"odd\">Water Cycle</li></ul></div>"
    ]
  }
]</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `if` clauses to compare your arrays and filter out same things.

(to do that and to create a new array without multiple things and values, you can use `for` loops)