# how to find duplicate in string and return index js

Tags: javascript

need to return index of second occurrence if no duplicate return not found

```js
const forAll = (str) => {
  var forAllmini;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    forAllmini = (str[i] != str[i+1]) ? 'not found': `@ index ${i}`;
  }
  return forAllmini
}

console.log(forAll('carrot'))
```

i tried this but i only get 'not found'

Comment: You overwrite `forAllmini` every time you loop, so it's only returning the last comparison. Once you find it, break your loop and return.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656708/check-for-repeated-characters-in-a-string-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to find repeated chars you can use a set and check it like this:

```js
const forAll = (str) => {
  const visited = new Set();
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(visited.has(str[i])) return `@ index ${i}`;
    visited.add(str[i]);
  }
  return 'not found'
}

console.log(forAll('carrot'))
```

Comment: thanks but why are you using set and not something else

Comment: because set allows you to check if the value exist in the "array" in a better efficient way than others

Comment: i don't understand why u add str[i] and why it doesn't work without adding

Comment: I add str[i] because once you visit this letter it's visited

Answer (score 1):

Because the `forAllmini` is overwritten:

```js
const forAll = (str) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if(str[i] == str[i+1]) return `@ index ${i}`;
  }
  return 'not found';
}

console.log(forAll('carrot'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to break your `for` like this:

```js
const forAll = (str) => {
  var forAllmini;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    forAllmini = (str[i] != str[i+1]) ? 'not found': `@ index ${i}`;
    if (forAllmini != 'not found') {
      break;
    }
  }
  return forAllmini
}

console.log(forAll('carrot'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You were mutating the variable in every iteration, and not breaking out when duplicate was found.

```js
const forAll = (str) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if((str[i] == str[i+1])) return `@ index ${i}`
  }
  return "not found"
}

console.log(forAll('carrot'))
```

Comment: so how can breake it?

Comment: i thought and i got it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the string one char at a time, starting from index `1`. You don't need to save intermediate results, just `return` from a loop to break out of it.

The problem with your `forAllmini` variable is that it is overridden on each loop iteration.

```js
function forAll(input) {
  for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i += 1) { // start at index 1, not 0!
    if (input[i - 1] === input[i]) { // check if previous char === current char
      return `@ index ${i - 1}`; // return index of first doubled character
    }
  }
  return 'not found';
}



console.log(forAll('carrot'));
console.log(forAll('none'));
```